# Envio de datos a través de formulario de contacto HTML, usando PHP

Tags: php, html

Esta es mi primera pregunta en este foro, ante todo agradecer a la comunidad el esfuerzo de leer mi pregunta. Tengo un problema desde hace más de 1 mes, que no ha habido manera de solucionar, probando y probando, al final me he decantado por este foro, dada su excelente prestigio, en fin os explico que sucede.

Tengo un formulario normal y corriente como el de cualquier web, simple, pido 4 datos, nombre, correo, asunto y mensaje, sucede que el script que tengo me envía el correo pero sin ningún dato, o sea que me devuelve un correo sin remitente y no se quien lo envia.

Os adjunto el HTML y el script de php, al parecer todo esta correcto, pero el problema es que no "setea" la información pasada por el formulario y por lo tanto me llegan los correos vacios de contenido, o al menos el contenido que importa es desconocido.

Código html:

```
<form action="php/mail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="name_lastname" type="text" id="name_surname"  class="validate" >
            <label for="name_surname">Nom Cognom</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="to_address" type="email" id="email" class="validate" >
            <label for="email">E-mail Adreça</label>
          </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" class="validate" >
            <label for="subject">Assumpte</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" class="materialize-textarea" ></textarea>
            <label for="message">Missatge</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn dark-bg waves-effect" value="ENVIAR MISSATGE">

</form>
```

Y ahora el código en php:

```
<?php 
    $field_name = $_POST['name_lastname'];
    $field_email = $_POST['to_address'];
    $field_subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail_to = 'info@iitec.cat';
    $subject = 'FORMULARI WEB iitec.cat'.$field_subject;

    $body_message = 'From: ' .$field_name."\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' .$field_email."\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Subject: ' .$field_subject."\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: ' .$field_message; "\r\n";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: "\n"' .$field_email ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: "\n"'.$field_email ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Name: "\n"' .$field_name ."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script languaje="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Gràcies pel teu missatge, Contacteré amb tu el més aviat possible.');
        window.location = '/index.html';
    </script>

<?php 
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('El missatge no s\'ha pogut enviar, envia directament un correu a info@iitec.cat, gràcies');
        window.location = '/index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}

?>
```

Bueno esto es todo, espero que sea suficiente. Gracias por vuestro tiempo y hasta pronto.
Un saludo.

Comment: podrías agregar el código html

Comment: No se si es el código php completo, pero extraño la parte donde recibes lo enviado desde el formulario y lo asignas a las variables que estás ocupando para enviar el correo, que debería verse algo así: $field_name = $_POST['nombre_campo']; Y si pudieras agregar el código HTML como lo pidió josego también ayudaría a encontrar el problema.<br><br>
Saludos.

Comment: @Enric No me queda claro: ¿sin ningún dato o sólo sin remitente? ¿Por qué no vas depurando por partes? Primero podrías hacer que el PHP imprima los valores recibidos y lo que va a enviar como mail, y luego depurar el código del envío por separado. Intenta hacer un [mcve]

Comment: No recibo ningún dato, solo aparece una parte del usuario de mi hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Veo un pequeño error en tus encabezados `headers`, no has concatenado correctamente (From, Replay-to y Name).

Tu código:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: "\n"' .$field_email ."\r\n";
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$headers .= 'Reply-To: "\n"'.$field_email ."\r\n";
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$headers .= 'Name: "\n"' .$field_name ."\r\n";
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Código actualizado:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . "\n" .$field_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To:' . "\n" . $field_email ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Name:' . "\n" .$field_name . "\r\n";
```

Otro pequeño error en `$body_message` como te han mencionado.

Tu código:

```
$body_message .= 'Message: ' .$field_message; "\r\n";
                                          ^^^^
```

Código actualizado:

```
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $field_message . "\r\n";
```

> **Solución:**

Hice un `var_dump($_POST);` y como resultado me daba `NULL`, aun que todo estaba correcto, después de hacer pruebas en mi servidor elimine el atributo enctype y volví hacer el var_dump y su resultado fue:

```
array(5) { ["name_lastname"]=> string(6) "Daniel" ["to_address"]=> string(15) "email@email.com" ["subject"]=> string(13) "Soy el asunto" ["message"]=> string(33) "soy una duda desde el formulario." ["Submit"]=> string(15) "ENVIAR MISSATGE" }
```

Conclusión eliminada enctype="text/plain" sí que recibe los datos y el correo correctamente.

Comment: He hecho los cambios que sugerís, pero sigue igual, si os sirve de pista ahora me indice como remitente mi usuario cuando entro en el cpanel, sigue saliendo todo en blanco, excepto los indicadores de nombre, email, subject y comentario, ¿No creéis que podría ser un problema del hosting?.Muchas Gracias.

Comment: He hecho algunas pruebas en mi servidor, con tu script, hice un `var_dump($_POST);` y como resultado me daba 0, es decir, no obtiene los datos, cuando todo esta bien, haciendo pruebas, eliminado enctype="text/plain", si que recibo los datos: `array(5) { ["name_lastname"]=> string(6) "Daniel" ["to_address"]=> string(15) "email@email.com" ["subject"]=> string(13) "Soy el asunto" ["message"]=> string(33) "soy una duda desde el formulario." ["Submit"]=> string(15) "ENVIAR MISSATGE" }`, y tambien me llega el correo correctamente, Prueba en eliminar enctype="text/plain" y me comentas.

Comment: Dicho y hecho, lo he quitado y funciona perfectamente, mil gracias, después de más de 1 mes queda solucionado, eres el p... amo. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro amig@, que al final lo solucionaste, lo dejare comentado en mi respuesta tambien. Si te ha servido la respuesta, podrias aceptarla como valido. Un saludo y suerte en tu proyecto.

Comment: Dalo por cerrado y por hecho, me quito el sombrero con esta comunidad, sois geniales.

Comment: El que hace la prejunta debe aceptar la respuesta amig@, yo no puedo. Ayudar siempre esta bien :), y bienvenido por cierto a SOes.

Comment: @EnricCanalda Para aceptar la respuesta, tienes que ir a la respuesta que fue correcta y gusto donde puedes dejar un voto positivo o negativo puedes aceptarla y saldrá una `V` en verde, así sabrán otros usuarios que dicha respuesta te ha solucionado el problema. Te bonificara tanto a ti como a mí. Te dejo un enlace con más detalle: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas